# Catalina doesn't allow modifying process memory using wine32on64?

Tags: macos, catalina, memory, wine

Hopefully this is the correct place to ask this question.

I know that Catalina has placed a lot of security restrictions to protect the user, but is one of them supposedly stopping applications from modifying memory process? I've tried looking, but couldn't find anything that might be stopping it.

The .exe that I run is waiting for a game's process to start, grabs the PID, and then edits the process to fix a known bug that stops the game from launching.

`boot-args="no32exec=0"` has already been set and the SIP has been disabled.

The original creator of the fix has stopped working on the project, and I don't know much about modifying process memory to figure it out. This is the error that is thrown. It's pretty general.

`wine: Unhandled page fault on write access to 0x7ffe0010 at address 0x1007:0x0040158c (thread 0086).`